# Specman e wait until threads finish (non time consuming method)

Tags: specman, e

Is there any way to get unit3.thread() to run after the other two threads?

```
run() is also
{
    start unit1.thread();
    start unit2.thread();
    unit3.thread();
};
```

I would like threads in unit 1 and 2 to run in parallel and for thread 3 to run after they have both completed. However since run() is not a time consuming method solutions such as:

```
all of
{
    {
        unit1.thread();
    };
    {
        unit2.thread();
    }
};
unit3.thread();
```

Are not allowed.

Is there any way to make unit3.thread() wait until the previous threads are finished?

Comment: As you have stated correctly, the run() method of any_struct is not a TCM, and therefore cannot
Consume time. This is why you cannot directly invoke a TCM from the run() method. What most people do is to
create a wrapper TCM and start it from the run() method. In this wrapper TCM, you can schedule the executions
Of your TCMs like unit3.thread() and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with events by manually firing events when `unit1` and `unit2` are done:

```
extend sys {
   event u1_done;
   event u2_done;
   run() is also {
     all of {
       { unit1.thread(); }
       { unit2.thread(); }
     };
   };
   on @u1_done and @u2_done unit3.thread();
};
```

Then in `unit1` and `unit2` issue these statements when you are done:

```
emit u1_done;
```

and for `unit2`:

```
emit u2_done;
```

I don't have access to Specman right now, so the syntax may not be spot on, however I've used this technique.